# find a number whose sum is multiple of 10

Tags: c++

Problem is to find the number whose sum is multiple of 10 given n as number of digits, and t is test cases.
I got segmentation fault in this code.

```
using namespace std;
void print(int start, int end, int sum)
{
    if (start == end) {
        return;
    }
    while (start != 0) {
        sum = sum + start % 10;
        start = start / 10;
    }
    if (sum % 10 == 0) {
        cout << start << endl;
        return;
    }
    else {
        print(start + 1, end, 0);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {

        int n;
        cin >> n;
        int start = pow(10, n - 1);
        int end = pow(10, n);
        print(start, end, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Compute how many times print is going to get called and make sure you have enough Automatic storage for all of the parameters. You're going to have to find a different way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that at the point you recursively call `print(start + 1, end, 0);` the `start` variable is zero not the original value. I guess this is leading to a stack overflow.

There's no good reason to use recursion here (at least not in a language like C++). Replace the recursion with a loop, and don't forget to use a temporary variable to do the digit sum calculation instead of trashing the value of `start`.